# IE10 document mode to standard and browser mode to IE10

Tags: html, browser

Folks

we have a html page and when we open it in IE10 , 
it always open in

Browser mode : IE10
 
Document Mode:Quirk.

We need the IE browser to open the website in

Browser mode : IE10  
Document Mode : standards.

dhairya

Comment: Are you setting up the doctype properly for your page?

Comment: You need a doctype. See [my blog post](http://spudley.com/blog/keeping-ie-in-standards-mode) for a full article on how to keep IE in standards mode.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">

Answer (score 0):

Set the doctype, valid doctype for html5 is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: if we specify <!DOCTYPE html> and  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9"> on the same page , then it affects chrome browwser